# Android Architecture component LiveData - how to bind broadcastReceivers to lifecycle

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Using Android [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html) I'd like to be able to unregister and register many `BroadcastReceiver`s in the `onInactive()` and `onActive()` call backs. So I want to do something like this:

```
public class BroadcastRecieverLiveData extends LiveData<BroadCastReciever> {
    private BroadcastReciever reciever;
    private Context context;

    public BroadcastRecieverLiveData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
        filter.addAction("SOME_OTHER_ACTION");

        reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //do something based on the intent's action
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(reciever, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        if (reciever != null) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(reciever);
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking this could be a design pattern to be clean up of code instead of relaying on `onDestroy`. What are your thoughts on using LiveData this way? There is an example of using it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think for receivers, you should implement `LifecycleObserver`.
As per `LiveData` documentation from Google **[codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)**,

> Caution: Storing a reference to a Context or View in a ViewModel can
>   result in memory leaks. Avoid fields that reference instances of the
>   Context or View classes. The onCleared() method is useful to
>   unsubscribe or clear references to other objects with a longer
>   lifecycle, but not for clearing references to Context or View objects.

So, You should not do context intensive operation in LiveData.

Instead, take an example of below implementation,

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class ReceiverManager implements LifecycleObserver {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final MyBrodacastReceiver myBrodacastReceiver;

    public ReceiverManager(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner,
                           Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        myBrodacastReceiver = new MyBrodacastReceiver();
        lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);

    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    void registerYourReceiver() {
        mContext.registerReceiver(myBrodacastReceiver, new IntentFilter());
    }


    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    void unRegisterYourReceiver() {
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(myBrodacastReceiver);
    }

    private static class MyBrodacastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what you wrote is a memory leak because the activity context is never released right

Comment: @ j2emanue: Pass `application context` not, `activity` context!

Comment: @ j2emanue : Refere codelab mentioned in answer. It has location listener attached to it. Instead, you can use your broadcast receiver!

Comment: @AndiGeeky so.. if you have a reference to Context here as well, how is that better than the code in the question?
I mean, he can pass the application context there as well (using his code with extending livedata). What's the difference?